# How does a remote academic position work for a position in China?

Tags: job-search, job, china, remote-work

I just came across [this remote position](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/collections/recommended/?currentJobId=3560523232) on LinkedIn, which is for an assistant/associate professor position at a certain university in China, see the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm based in Europe, and it's showing up on my LinkedIn job feed. I wonder if it's at all possible since it specifies that it's a remote position. Logistically speaking, I'm a bit pessimistic about how that'll work if say, the position holder is based say in Berlin and wants to perform their responsibilities in China - there'll be a time difference and all sorts of difficulties associated with being thousands of miles away. So how does this really work? Is there anyone here who's in a similar position/situation?

EDIT: I messaged the WhatsApp number provided with a no. registered in the UK, and they replied this:

[image]

Any comment on that?

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but I would interpret this more as "position will be in Quzhou University, with some remote teaching in Paris". I doubt they are looking for somebody who is present in neither of the two universities.

Comment: @xLeitix Thanks, well in this case one would expect the use of the word 'hybrid' than that of 'remote' twice.

Comment: @ScienceMan You are right. I guess I am as confused as you are about this ad.

Comment: A scheme to work in france, while officially employed by a chinese university for the sake of dodging taxes or some local laws?

Comment: @Wouter It does seem strange about the ad, to be honest - I did go ahead and sent my application, needed only my CV, so why not. As for the local laws in Europe, it'd be declared as a freelance income and would be taxed, if one respects the laws. Now I can't comment on the part of the Chinese university that posted this ad.

Comment: It is extremely likely that this is simply a recruiting approach, bordering on spamming (even if the postings are "legit"), that are employed by some agencies on LinkedIn. They post these positions in many areas (as you could see from the employer's profile page) but the actual position is not necessarily remote.

Comment: @xngtng Thank you - please see the edit in my OP.

Comment: Doesn't your edit answer the question already?

Comment: This whole thing feels very scammy to me.

Comment: @Buffy Sorry for my dumb question, I think I'm still not cleat about how this will all work for successful candidates not based in China. I'm sure  I missed something from that edit. I see that it's a headhunting agency that screens the applications to match with Chinese universities, but then I wonder, why will a good uni will actually need a headhunter, given that the faculty can do a much better screening? Secondly, I don't understand why the originally advertised position was for Quzhou university, whereas after applying, it seems like a more generic application?

Comment: It just feels they didn't give us the whole picture before applying. Also, in their email, they didn't explain how the whole payment and other administrative process would work remotely? I can try to email Quzhou university about this and ask if it's a scam? But then again, when I go to the website of the headhunter, it looks legit!

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://www.fbi.gov/investigate/counterintelligence/the-china-threat/chinese-talent-plans

Comment: This is basically just spam, in LinkedIn you can search positions by geographical region, and they just insert their positions in China in other regions by pretending the positions are in other regions, but that is generally not true. Just look at the difference between position title and the actual position (associave vs all ranks).

Comment: @ScienceMan "_why will a good uni will actually need a headhunter,_". I am a native Chinese speaker, (I live in Taiwan, not mainland) I am not too sure Quchou university is a good university. According to [this](https://topuniversitieslist.com/quzhou-university/), The country rank is 426, the world rank is 7103.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I can't know for sure, the US FBI has warned about something that sounds similar:

[FBI > Counterintelligence > The China Threat](https://www.fbi.gov/investigate/counterintelligence/the-china-threat/chinese-talent-plans)

Some red flags include the up-front payment: they're going to give you a tempting bundle of cash right away, vague requirements (it doesn't seem like they have a specific position to fill, they just want people who fill a certain profile of *knowing things*), bizarre promises like a "talent title" which they insist is quite the honor, and easily faked duties like "provide leadership in".

I suspect the experience for different people with the program is different. They'll probably only hire you if they think you know something useful. Maybe for some it's a fairly legitimate gig: certainly people have defended the program as no different from any other hiring program. And, it's certainly sensible that a country like China that has access to money and is trying to improve their scientific position would use funding promises to attract talent there. But, similar programs have led to prosecutions in the US:

[US Attorney's Office (2021) Harvard University Professor Convicted of Making False Statements and Tax Offenses. *Press release of the US Attorney's Office, District of Massachusetts*, 21 December 2021](https://www.justice.gov/usao-ma/pr/harvard-university-professor-convicted-making-false-statements-and-tax-offenses)

[Former Cleveland Clinic researcher charged with fraud for failing to disclose China ties. *Cleveland.com*, 14 May 2020](https://www.cleveland.com/crime/2020/05/former-cleveland-clinic-researcher-charged-with-fraud-for-failing-to-disclose-china-ties.html)

[Long, J. (2020) Former Ohio State research pleads guilty for lying to FBI about ties to Chinese government. *The Lantern*, 12 November 2020](https://www.thelantern.com/2020/11/former-ohio-state-researcher-pleads-guilty-for-lying-to-fbi-about-ties-to-chinese-government/)

[Barry, E. and Kolata, G. (2020) China’s Lavish Funds Lured U.S. Scientists. What Did It Get in Return? *The New York Times*, 6 February 2020](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/06/us/chinas-lavish-funds-lured-us-scientists-what-did-it-get-in-return.html)

Basically, these cases state that the researchers worked "remotely" for the Chinese government, which meant they sent information to China for payment. For example:

> Under the terms of Lieber’s three-year Thousand Talents contract, WUT paid Lieber a salary of up to $50,000 per month, living expenses of up to $150,000 and awarded him more than $1.5 million to establish a research lab at WUT. In 2018 and 2019, Lieber lied to federal authorities about his involvement in the Thousand Talents Plan and his affiliation with WUT.

The legal problems came up when the scientists failed to disclose these connections, running into tax laws and laws against lying to government agencies.

I suspect what happens is that, if you are "hired", they'll make sure you get some money right away, make sure you've committed some crime in your home country like failing to report the income on taxes or to another employer, and blackmail by threatening to disclose the relationship, unless you provide information. The standard intelligence playbook would be to first ask you to share relatively innocuous things, but ultimately they seem mostly after information that will let Chinese companies get a jump start on a technology, or have insider information to make business decisions.

Comment: Upfront payment is not uncommon, even for staff recruited within China.  I believe it is standard for universities in China, especially those who want to recruit good staff.

Comment: This is fascinating (+1) and extremely useful information.  I also received a variation of this same advertisement for remote university positions at Quzhou (in Australia) and I must admit that I also found the requirements and proposed position extremely confusing.  I agree that it's legitimate in principle for Chinese universities to offer remote positions to Western academics (and there could be many benefits of this) but it's great to also hear these warnings relating to red flags and legal breaches that have arisen from such arrangements.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, another variant is this one: https://cen.acs.org/research-integrity/Highly-cited-chemist-suspended-claiming-to-be-affiliated-with-Russian-and-Saudi-universities/101/i12 where a researcher is paid to add an affiliation. I don't know if that's part of these Chinese "Talent" programs, but it could be another way for a remote institution to get some "value" for their money, in a manner that is ethically a bit questionable

Comment: Fascinating stuff --- what a great answer.  I had heard of some prosecutions like this in the news, but was not aware of the systematic nature of the Talent programs.  Thanks for providing such a great answer.